# __init__ method giving exception

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to run following program:

```
class Temp():

    def __init__(self):
        print 'hello world!'

    def main():
        temp = Temp()
        print 'here i am'

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  class Temp():
File "test.py", line 11, in Temp
  main()
File "test.py", line 7, in main
  temp = Temp()
```

Why i am getting this error?

Comment: what are you trying to do? why are you defining main as a class method for Temp, and initializing an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unindent `main()` and what's below it, right now it's a method of `Temp` not standalone function. You're essentially trying to call a method without an instance of `Temp`.

Indentation is how python determines what is in a method, class, loop or not. See here:

**EDIT**:

```
class Temp():
    def __init__(self):
        # this method is in Temp
        pass

    def prettyPrint(self):
        # this method is also in temp
        print("I'm in temp")

def prettyPrint(self):
    #this is not in Temp (notice the indentation change)
    print("I'm not in temp")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #this is not in temp either
    t = Temp()
    t.prettyPrint()
    prettyPrint(None)
```